# autohotkey to put my laptop to sleep works once

Tags: autohotkey

The script below puts my laptop to sleep when I hit alt+0, it works once at the beginning, until I log back in, and then it doesn't.

After the first attempt, the script doesn't adhere to the 2 sleeps I inserted, it blazes right through each line, and doesn't put my laptop to sleep.  If I reload the script, it works.

Not sure why?

I am using Windows 7 64 bit

```
!0::


send ^{Esc}

send {Right}

send ^{Right}

sleep 2000

send {Up}

sleep 2000

send {enter}


return
```

Comment: Are you using latest version of AutoHotkey from ahkscript.org ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
!0::
    DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0)
Return
```

Comment: although, I still would like to understand why my script doesn't work?

Comment: It's usually related to sending the keystrokes too fast. Changing the input method can help too. Something like [SetKeyDelay](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm), 20, 20 in the beginning of your script might help

Comment: that's what I thought , thus the 2 sleep inserts, but those 2 sleeps should have solved the problem, but blazed right through the script as I mentioned.  I think this must be a bug.

Comment: Have you tried setting the keydelays? 2 sleeps might not be enough. I highly doubt this is a bug.

Comment: awesome, you were right. I also inserted sleeps after each line which also worked...